# How to utilize a global variable in spark, caching or BlockManager?

Tags: python, apache-spark, caching, global-variables, spark-streaming

I have this mistake with spark streaming, I need to store a global variable (like a counter) to use in the various executors, which only increments in the driver. *Spark accumulators* can not be used because they have local context for every executors. I have also tried to use *spark caching*, but it allows only storing entire data sets, not just an integer variable. *BlockManager* could be a good solution but from the documentation provided by spark it is difficult to understand anything. 
I hope you can help to find a solution.

N.B: I use spark with python

Answer (score 1):

Spark provides something called broadcast variable to hold cache-data.
A Broadcast variable is read-only cache where every executor holds its own copy. Hence, any updates to it are not visible to other executors. Also, note that a Broadcast object is not Serializable and needs to be final. So, one cannot update it.

Some naive options to hold your cache-data:

1. Restart the Spark Context every time the cache-data changes, with a new Broadcast Variable.
2. Host the cached data behind a REST api and look-it-up via foreachRDD or forEachPartition.

One approach that I tried and which worked out for me is Rebroadcasting cache data periodically. Please find my blog on [How to weave a periodically changing cached-data with your streaming application](https://spoddutur.github.io/spark-notes/weaving_a_changing_broadcast_variable) for further details where I gave a demo to handle the same. Hope it gives you a perspective on how to go about using a changing cached-data in spark.